# A noun to describe an intention not to use humor when not necessary

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, humor, personality

I am seeking a noun that would describe a person's attempt to refrain themselves from being "cool" in responding (perhaps to an email message), often contrary to their humorous nature - an intentional approach where they filter out unnecessary or excessive humor (as in talking to an individual they don't know well) and want to sound professional, succinct and to-the-merit.

It should not mean a lack of humor of the person, instead it should emphasize they purposely avoid humor where it can be unmet.

As I am writing a short article, I would need a swift single word to act as a sub-header. I assume there is one. *Strictness* would sound too strict for that though.

Would *reservedness* be a choice perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say that this person is showing [self-restraint](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+self-restraint):

> restraint imposed by oneself on one's own actions; self-control.
>
> synonyms:  self-control, restraint, self-discipline, self-possession, self-command, willpower, moderation, temperance, abstemiousness, abstention
>
> "please exercise some self-restraint and don't start screaming when he gets here"

Answer (score 1):

I would use *formal* or maybe *serious*, depending upon the context.

Comment: 'Sober' could also work, or 'soberness'.

Answer (score 0):

***I forbore to respond with humour***.

***She forbears to laugh at the old man making such a fool of himself***.